# magnific-popup - re-initiate on ajax content

Tags: magnific-popup

I've the following code to initiate Magnific-Popup on my elements and everything works fine:

```
$( '.client-logo-overlay' ).magnificPopup({

            //modal: true,
            //closeBtnInside:true,
            //closeOnBgClick: true,
            //showCloseBtn: true,
            delegate: 'a',
            type:     'ajax',
            ajax: {
                settings: {
                    url:  $( this ).attr( 'href' ),
                    type: 'POST'
                }
            },
            callbacks: {
                parseAjax: function( mfpResponse ) {
                    var html = $( mfpResponse.data ).find( 'article' );
                    mfpResponse.data = $( '<div>', { class: 'white-popup small' } ).append( html );
                }
            }

        });
```

However, when loading some content using AJAX, MagnificPopup doesn't work anymore on those newly inserted elements - what am I missing.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the behavior i.e. message when it doesn't work?

Comment: `$( '.client-logo-overlay' )` only catches the elements which are already loaded when it's called. If you add new element later you have to call it again for these elements

Comment: I was under the impression that if I'd use delegate: 'a' if would work, but I guess not.